# failing to download Cyhunspell

Tags: python, nlp, hunspell

I'm trying to install `cyhunspell` and also install c++ build tools but still fails.

> win11

```
pip install CyHunspell
Collecting CyHunspell
  Using cached CyHunspell-1.3.4.tar.gz (2.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: cacheman>=2.0.6 in c:\users\darth\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from CyHunspell) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil>=2.1.0 in c:\users\darth\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from cacheman>=2.0.6->CyHunspell) (5.9.5)
Building wheels for collected packages: CyHunspell
  Building wheel for CyHunspell (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for CyHunspell (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [65 lines of output]
      C:\Users\darth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w4ajqljo\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:745: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: Invalid dash-separated options
      !!
          ********************************************************************************
          Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future
          versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead.

          By 2023-Sep-26, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
          or your builds will no longer be supported.

          See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
          ********************************************************************************

  !!
    opt = self.warn_dash_deprecation(opt, section)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
  copying hunspell\platform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
  copying hunspell\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
  copying hunspell\hunspell.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
  copying hunspell\thread.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
  copying hunspell\hunspell.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
  copying hunspell\hunspell.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
  copying hunspell\thread.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
  copying hunspell\hunspell.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hunspell
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
  copying dictionaries\en_AU.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
  copying dictionaries\en_CA.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
  copying dictionaries\en_GB.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
  copying dictionaries\en_NZ.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
  copying dictionaries\en_US.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
  copying dictionaries\en_ZA.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
  copying dictionaries\test.aff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
  copying dictionaries\en_AU.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
  copying dictionaries\en_CA.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
  copying dictionaries\en_GB.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
  copying dictionaries\en_NZ.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
  copying dictionaries\en_US.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
  copying dictionaries\en_ZA.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
  copying dictionaries\test.dic -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\dictionaries
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\libs
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\libs\msvc
  copying libs\msvc\libhunspell-msvc11-x64.lib -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\libs\msvc
  copying libs\msvc\libhunspell-msvc11-x86.lib -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\libs\msvc
  copying libs\msvc\libhunspell-msvc14-x64.lib -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\libs\msvc
  copying libs\msvc\libhunspell-msvc14-x86.lib -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\libs\msvc
  running build_ext
  building 'hunspell.hunspell' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\hunspell
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\darth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4nl9a0z_\cyhunspell_61ffa63add954ac0b0c0ed7e17889d49\hunspell -IC:\Users\darth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4nl9a0z_\cyhunspell_61ffa63add954ac0b0c0ed7e17889d49\external\hunspell-1.3.3\src -IC:\Users\darth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\darth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tphunspell\hunspell.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\hunspell\hunspell.obj /EHsc /DHUNSPELL_STATIC
  hunspell.cpp
  hunspell\hunspell.cpp(2373): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  hunspell\hunspell.cpp(7426): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  hunspell\hunspell.cpp(7601): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  hunspell\hunspell.cpp(8951): error C2105: '++' needs l-value
  hunspell\hunspell.cpp(8953): error C2105: '--' needs l-value
  hunspell\hunspell.cpp(10965): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
  hunspell\hunspell.cpp(10981): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for CyHunspell
Failed to build CyHunspell
ERROR: Could not build wheels for CyHunspell, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

How can I fix what I should do?